# How to define a list environment which has two label: one is as usual and another lay into the margin?

Tags: lists

How to define a list environment which has two counter label: one is as usual and another lay into the margin?

Like this:

```
L margin                                      R margin
|                                                    |
|maintext maintext maintext maintext maintext maintex|
|t maintext maintext maintext maintext maintext      |
|---------------begin list environment---------------|
|1. blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla | Ans on P37
|blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla| (or Reference \cite[92])
|blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla| (or See Appendix B.3)
|blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla bla| (or 5 points/100 points.)
```

Comment: How is `Ans on P37` (or others) obtained?

Comment: @Werner I think handling with it by putting a \label{listA-problem1} on anser's \item, and a \pageref{listA-problem1} on the corresponding problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *might* be what you're after...

Using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to generate parameter-specific lists, with references added to the margins using `\marginpar`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{answers}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[questions,answers]{%
  label=\arabic*.,
  align=left,
  labelwidth=1.5em,
  itemindent=2em,
  leftmargin=!,
  labelsep=0.5em}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}

\begin{questions}
  \item \leavevmode\marginpar{See Section~\ref{sec:answers}}\lipsum[1]
  \item \leavevmode\marginpar{A margin note.}\lipsum[2]
  \item \leavevmode\marginpar{Ans on p.~\pageref{ans3}}\lipsum[3]
\end{questions}

\section{Answers}\label{sec:answers}

\begin{questions}
  \item \label{ans1}\lipsum[4]
  \item \label{ans2}\lipsum[5]
  \item \label{ans3}\lipsum[6]
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where can I find an explanation of how `\leavevmode` here enables `\marginpar` to be placed on the correct line?

Comment: @A.Ellett: `\leavevmode` starts the paragraph (and therefore also the `\item` numbering). Without it you're in vertical mode, leaving the vertical position of the `\marginpar` dangling between baseline skips (I guess). I'm no wizz in that regard...

Answer (score 2):

This is an improvement over Werner's answer, using `\marginnote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,lipsum,marginnote}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{answers}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[questions,answers]{%
  label=\arabic*.,
  align=left,
  labelwidth=1.5em,
  itemindent=2em,
  leftmargin=!,
  labelsep=0.5em}

\newcommand{\question}[1]{%
  \item\marginnote{\sffamily#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Questions}

\begin{questions}
  \question{See Section~\ref{sec:answers}}\lipsum[1]
  \question{A margin note.}\lipsum[2]
  \question{Ans on p.~\pageref{ans3}}\lipsum[3]
\end{questions}

\section{Answers}\label{sec:answers}

\begin{answers}
  \item \label{ans1}\lipsum[4]
  \item \label{ans2}\lipsum[5]
  \item \label{ans3}\lipsum[6]
\end{answers}

\end{document}
```

The `\sffamily` is just for making the reference better distinguishable from the context, but is of course optional.

[image]